# Game loop with keyboard listener

Tags: c++, opengl, glut

For a C++/OpenGL game I'm making I want both a keyboard input handler, and a constant screen update, because there are constant moving parts in the game.
Now I've read that I can use glutKeyboardFunc() for the keyboard listener, and a simple while loop for the constant screen update (while gameRunning {...}).

But how can I combine the two, because if I use the while loop the key listener will never get called, because the game is still running the while loop.

Comment: Why not set it before starting the loop?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems you are looking for [glutIdleFunc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15670580/whats-the-point-of-glutidlefunc-in-freeglut) you will have a constant screen update (remember to call `glutPostRedisplay` at the end). Though you won't have a fixed time step (it's not guaranteed to be called in constant intervals). must read [fix your timestep](http://gafferongames.com/game-physics/fix-your-timestep/).

IMHO you need to ditch GLUT all together and get a better library like SDL or GLFW.

Answer (score 1):

[This tutorial at Lighthouse3d.com](http://www.lighthouse3d.com/tutorials/glut-tutorial) covers everything you are talking about.

Key observation: You don't use your own 'while' loop to create animation.  The loop is built into the function `glutMainLoop()`, which you call once you have set everything up.

Answer (score 0):

You could use multiple threads, one for display, one for keyboard capture, and one for physics updates. If the physics needs to run at a fixed frequency, here is a snippet of code for Windows XP or later that uses a high frequency counter and sleep if there there enough "spare" time:

```
typedef unsigned long long UI64;    /* unsigned 64 bit int */
#define FREQ 400                    /* 400 hz */
static LARGE_INTEGER liPerfFreq;    /* 64 bit frequency */
LARGE_INTEGER liPerfTemp;           /* used for query */
UI64 uFreq = FREQ;                  /* process frequency */
UI64 uOrig;                         /* original tick */
UI64 uWait;                         /* tick rate / freq */
UI64 uRem = 0;                      /* tick rate % freq */
UI64 uPrev;                         /* previous tick based on original tick */
UI64 uDelta;                        /* current tick - previous */
UI64 u2ms;                          /* 2ms of ticks */
UI64 i;                          
    timeBeginPeriod(1);             /* set period to 1ms */
    Sleep(128);                     /* wait for it to stabilize */
    u2ms = ((UI64)(liPerfFreq.QuadPart)+499) / ((UI64)500);
    QueryPerformanceCounter(&liPerfTemp);
    uOrig = uPrev = liPerfTemp.QuadPart;
    for(i = 0; i < (uFreq*30); i++){
        /* physics step code goes here */
        /* update uWait and uRem based on uRem */
        uWait = ((UI64)(liPerfFreq.QuadPart) + uRem) / uFreq;
        uRem  = ((UI64)(liPerfFreq.QuadPart) + uRem) % uFreq;
        /* wait for uWait ticks */
        while(1){
            QueryPerformanceCounter(&liPerfTemp);
            uDelta = (UI64)(liPerfTemp.QuadPart - uPrev);
            if(uDelta >= uWait)
                break;
            if((uWait - uDelta) > u2ms)
                Sleep(1);   /* up to 2ms on win xp */
        }
    }
```