# OpenGL moving object doesn't work

Tags: c++, opengl, rotation

I just want to do horizontally moving wheel. There's a code but it doesn't work - wheel just moving as a circle, leaving traces. I've tried to `glTranslatef(0.0f, moveY, 0.0f);` but it doesn't work too.

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <math.h>
#include <GL/freeglut.h>
#include <GL\GL.h>

#define window_width  1080  
#define window_height 720 

GLfloat angle; // wheel's rotator
GLfloat moveX; // wheel's mover by X

void DrawCircle(float cx, float cy, float r, int num_segments) {
    glLoadIdentity();

    glTranslatef(0, 0, -10); // set place where wheel starts to draw

    glRotatef(angle, 0.0f, 0.0f, -0.1f); // rotate our wheel. it works correctly I think

    glTranslatef(moveX, 0.0f, 0.0f); // but it makes me wonder. moving circle by X doesn't work 

    // part of a circle
    glBegin(GL_TRIANGLE_FAN);
    glColor3f(255, 255, 255);
    for (int ii = 0; ii < num_segments; ii++) {
        double twicePi = 2.0 * 3.142;
        float theta = 2.0f * 3.1415926f * float(ii) / float(num_segments);
        float x = r * cosf(theta);
        float y = r * sinf(theta);
        glVertex2f(x + cx, y + cy);
    }

    glEnd();

    // second part of a circle
    int i, x, y;
    double radius = 1.20;    

    glColor3ub(0.0, 0.0, 0.0);
    double twicePi = 2.0 * 3.142;
    x = 0, y = 0;
    glBegin(GL_TRIANGLE_FAN); 
    glVertex2f(x, y); 
    for (i = 0; i <= 20; i++) {
        glVertex2f(
            (x + (radius * cos(i * twicePi / 20))),
            (y + (radius * sin(i * twicePi / 20)))
        );
    }
    glEnd();
    // there's an end of drawning of a circle

    // this is where wheel starts to rotate and move
    angle += 0.02f;
    moveX += 0.00005f;



    // there are spokes of a wheel
    glBegin(GL_LINES);
        glColor3f(255, 255, 255);
        glVertex3f(0.0, 0.0, 0.0);
        glVertex3f(0.0, -1.2f, 0.0);
    glEnd();

    glBegin(GL_LINES);
        glColor3f(255, 255, 255);
        glVertex3f(0.0, 0.0, 0.0);
        glVertex3f(0.0, 1.2f, 0.0);
    glEnd();

    glBegin(GL_LINES);
        glColor3f(255, 255, 255);
        glVertex3f(0.0, 0.0, 0.0);
        glVertex3f(1.2f, 0.0, 0.0);
    glEnd();

    glBegin(GL_LINES);
        glColor3f(255, 255, 255);
        glVertex3f(0.0, 0.0, 0.0);
        glVertex3f(-1.2f, 0.0, 0.0);
    glEnd();

    glBegin(GL_LINES);
        glColor3f(255, 255, 255);
        glVertex3f(0.0, 0.0, 0.0);
        glVertex3f(1.f, 1.f, 0.0);
    glEnd();

    glBegin(GL_LINES);
        glColor3f(255, 255, 255);
        glVertex3f(0.0, 0.0, 0.0);
        glVertex3f(-1.f, 1.f, 0.0);
    glEnd();

    glBegin(GL_LINES);
        glColor3f(255, 255, 255);
        glVertex3f(0.0, 0.0, 0.0);
        glVertex3f(1.f, -1.f, 0.0);
    glEnd();

    glBegin(GL_LINES);
        glColor3f(255, 255, 255);
        glVertex3f(0.0, 0.0, 0.0);
        glVertex3f(-1.f, -1.f, 0.0);
    glEnd();

    glBegin(GL_LINES);
        glColor3f(255, 255, 255);
        glVertex3f(0.0, 0.0, 0.0);
        glVertex3f(1.2f, 0.5f, 0.0);
    glEnd();

    glBegin(GL_LINES);
        glColor3f(255, 255, 255);
        glVertex3f(0.0, 0.0, 0.0);
        glVertex3f(-1.2f, -0.5f, 0.0);
    glEnd();

    glBegin(GL_LINES);
        glColor3f(255, 255, 255);
        glVertex3f(0.0, 0.0, 0.0);
        glVertex3f(-1.2f, -0.5f, 0.0);
    glEnd();

    glBegin(GL_LINES);
        glColor3f(255, 255, 255);
        glVertex3f(0.0, 0.0, 0.0);
        glVertex3f(-1.2f, 0.5f, 0.0);
    glEnd();

    glBegin(GL_LINES);
        glColor3f(255, 255, 255);
        glVertex3f(0.0, 0.0, 0.0);
        glVertex3f(1.2f, -0.5f, 0.0);
    glEnd();

}


void main_loop_function() {
    DrawCircle(0.0, 0.0, 1.45, 200);
    glutSwapBuffers();
}

void GL_Setup(int width, int height) {
    glViewport(0, 0, width, height);
    glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
    gluPerspective(45, (float) width / height, 0.1, 100);
    glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
}

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    glutInit(&argc, argv);
    glutInitWindowSize(window_width, window_height);
    glutInitDisplayMode(GLUT_RGB | GLUT_DOUBLE);
    glutCreateWindow("trata");
    glutIdleFunc(main_loop_function);
    GL_Setup(window_width, window_height);
    glutMainLoop();
}
```

Comment: Could you please add screenshots with results? And what does not works? I think you need call glRotatef before glTranslatef.

Comment: @Unick you are awesome!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is just a quick fix to make your code work so you can fuhrtherly develop and debug it. I see a number of critical issues in your code:

(0) Mixing POSIX paths with Windows paths:

```
#include <GL/freeglut.h>
#include <GL\GL.h>
```

(1) including custom headers and expecting the community to guess what is it about. I commented it out.

```
//#include "stdafx.h"
```

(2) Miswriting *casts* as functions - it should be:

```
    float theta = 2.0f * 3.1415926f * (float)ii / (float)num_segments;
```

(3) No `glutDisplayFunc` in your code. You should register something like:

```
glutDisplayFunc(main_display_function);
```

before registering `glutIdleFunc()`. Then, in your code you should define it somewhat in the following way:

```
void main_display_function() {
    DrawCircle(0.0, 0.0, 1.45, 200);
    glutSwapBuffers();    
}
```

(4) Even in that function you don't clear the "window content" before redrawing:

```
void DrawCircle(float cx, float cy, float r, int num_segments) {
    glClearColor (0., 0., 0., 1);
    glClear (GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
    {…   …   … } //the rest of your code
}
```

(5) Passing color values of *wrong data type*:

```
    glColor3f(255, 255, 255);  //unsigned byte passed, float expected!
```

or

```
    glColor3ub(0.0, 0.0, 0.0); //float passed, unsigned byte expected!
```

There are few more issues which directly address your question - you will *easily* understand and *debug* them yourself, once you fix the program to work correctly (the order of calling `glRotatef` and the second `glTranslatef`, correctly computing `movex`, drawing beams or spokes). Please, also take a look at [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15670580/whats-the-point-of-glutidlefunc-in-freeglut).

PS. Your using a C++ compiler to build this program doesn't make it a C++ code. There is not a single line of C++ specific code in your program. Also, both OpenGL and GLUT are plain-C APIs.

Comment: oh my god `glClear (GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);` was very useful. ty again!

Comment: There's still much code which is inefficient, such as dividing constants inside the loop: `twicePi / 20`, or redundant: all the repeated `glColor3f()` calls for the spokes, when you in fact use only one color for all...

Comment: sorry i'm new in opengl.
what's wrong with `twicePi /20`?

Comment: You divide two constants for 20 times. Like you have calculated `twicePi` outside the loop to prevent multiplying constants, you could have also defined `float rad = twicePi/20.`(or whichever number of fans) outside the loop. This has nothing to do with OpenGL. In every computer language or API it would be the same, because it is _math_.